# How can I sum a column of a list?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a Python array, like so:

```
[[1,2,3],
 [1,2,3]]
```

I can add the row by doing `sum(array[i])`, how can I sum a column, using a double for loop?

I.E. for the first column, I could get 2, then 4, then 6.

Comment: consider moving to numpy ndarrays for nicer slicing (it would be `a[:,i].sum()` in your case)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using a `for` loop (in a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions)):

```
data = [[1,2,3],
        [1,2,3]]

column = 1
print(sum(row[column] for row in data))  # -> 4
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
a = [[1,2,3],
     [1,2,3]]

print [sum(x) for x in zip(*a)]
```

[zip function description](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a loop, use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose the list, then take the desired column:

```
sum(list(zip(*data)[i]))
```

(Note in 2.x, `zip()` returns a list, so you don't need the `list()` call).

Edit: The simplest solution to this problem, without using `zip()`, would probably be:

```
column_sum = 0
for row in data:
    column_sum += row[i]
```

We just loop through the rows, taking the element and adding it to our total.

This is, however, less efficient and rather pointless given we have built-in functions to do this for us. In general, use `zip()`.

Comment: I saw that on another answer, but I want to know how to do it this way, before learning how to do it more efficiently.

Comment: Temporarily transposing the entire matrix in order to sum one of the resulting rows doesn't seem very efficient to me...nor does not using the built-in `sum()` function to do it (in the code in the edit).

Answer (score 5):

```
[sum(row[i] for row in array) for i in range(len(array[0]))]
```

That should do it. `len(array[0])` is the number of columns, so `i` iterates through those. The generator expression `row[i] for row in array` goes through all of the rows and selects a single column, for each column number.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is this:

```
sumcolumn=data.sum(axis=0)

print (sumcolumn)
```

Comment: It looks like this answer assumes numpy, but does improve on the other numpy answer. It may help others if you fill out this code example

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guidelines there to provide quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `zip()`:

```
In [16]: lis=[[1,2,3],
   ....:  [1,2,3]]

In [17]: map(sum,zip(*lis))
Out[17]: [2, 4, 6]
```

or with a simple for loops:

```
In [25]: for i in xrange(len(lis[0])):
    summ=0
    for x in lis:
        summ+=x[i]
    print summ
   ....:     
2
4
6
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), which has more advanced array features.
One of which is to easily sum a column:

```
from numpy import array

a = array([[1,2,3],
 [1,2,3]])

column_idx = 1
a[:, column_idx].sum() # ":" here refers to the whole array, no filtering.
```

Comment: I think your answer is wrong. You probably meant a.sum(column_idx), but even that would be wrong too because in order to get the sum by column as the OP asked you'd need column_idx = 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
a.sum(0)
```